# jquery: unbind a specific function leaving the other one

Tags: jquery, unbind

I have a simple question: i have two different functions binded to click event:

```
$("#selector").click(function one() {
// stuff
});

$("#selector").click(function two() {
// other stuff
});
```

I want to unbind only one of them. How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the bound functions into variables. After that you can unbind them using jQuery's .off()-method:

```js
(function($){

  var alert1 = function(){
    alert('1');
  }, alert2 = function(){
    alert('2');
  };
  
  // Bind alert1
  $('button').on('click',alert1);
  
  // Bind alert 2
  $('button').on('click',alert2);
  
  // Unbind alert2
  $('button').off('click',alert2);

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Alert</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [off function](https://api.jquery.com/off/) is what you are looking for

`The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on()`